# Get 403 Forbidden when trying to connect Gitlab API by Laravel

Tags: laravel, gitlab, gitlab-api

I try to pull list of user's repository through Gitlab API by using Laravel.
What I should do?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Did you first authenticate your self with Gitlab via there token system?

Comment: Your route is probably setup incorrectly